# multi-threaded fftw library on windows

Tags: c++, fftw

I've downloaded the precompiled windows DLLs from the website http://www.fftw.org/install/windows.html. I've also created the *.lib files. However, they don't include the multi-threading related functions `fftw_init_threads`, `fftw_plan_with_nthreads` and so on.

So, how do I use multi-threaded fftw on windows? Do I need to compile the code by myself?

**EDIT**: I've tried to build version 3.3.10 by myself using Visual Studio 2022. I'm compiling with the following flags set in the cmakesettings.json:

```
{
  "name": "x64-Release",
  "generator": "Ninja",
  "configurationType": "RelWithDebInfo",
  "buildRoot": "${projectDir}\\out\\build\\${name}",
  "installRoot": "${projectDir}\\out\\install\\${name}",
  "cmakeCommandArgs": "",
  "buildCommandArgs": "",
  "ctestCommandArgs": "",
  "inheritEnvironments": [ "msvc_x64_x64" ],
  "variables": [
    {
      "name": "ENABLE_SSE",
      "value": "False",
      "type": "BOOL"
    },
    {
      "name": "ENABLE_SSE2",
      "value": "True",
      "type": "BOOL"
    },
    {
      "name": "ENABLE_AVX2",
      "value": "True",
      "type": "BOOL"
    },
    {
      "name": "ENABLE_AVX",
      "value": "False",
      "type": "BOOL"
    },
    {
      "name": "ENABLE_FLOAT",
      "value": "True",
      "type": "BOOL"
    },
    {
      "name": "ENABLE_THREADS",
      "value": "True",
      "type": "BOOL"
    },
    {
      "name": "CMAKE_WINDOWS_EXPORT_ALL_SYMBOLS",
      "value": "True",
      "type": "BOOL"
    }
  ]
}
```

With this settings I'm still receiving the following linker errors:

> Creating library fftw3f_threads.lib and object fftw3f_threads.exp
> \fftw-3.3.10\out\build\x64-Release\api.c.obj : error LNK2001:
> unresolved external symbol fftwf_mksolver_ct_hook
> \fftw-3.3.10\out\build\x64-Release\api.c.obj : error LNK2001:
> unresolved external symbol fftwf_mksolver_hc2hc_hook
> \fftw-3.3.10\out\build\x64-Release\fftw3f_threads.dll : fatal error
> LNK1120: 2 unresolved externals

Comment: Looks like it: https://www.fftw.org/install/windows.html

Comment: @PaulSanders I've tried that, but I'm not able to resolve the issues above.

Comment: What source file(s) are those functions in?  Looks like they're not getting included in the build, although I wouldn't know why.

Comment: @PaulSanders Well, I don't know. I've searched in the whole fftw-3.3.10 folder, in every file, for the term `fftwf_mksolver_ct_hook` but it wasn't found ...

Answer (score 0):

OK, I think I've got it, pretty much.  At least, I can see where things are going off the rails.

Following on from the comments, FFTW macroises all its function names (and globals).  In `CONVENTION`, we read:

> NAME MANGLING: use `X(foo)` for external names instead of `fftw_foo`.
> `X(foo)` expands to `fftwf_foo` or `fftw_foo`, depending on the
> precision.

So now we know that `fftwf_mksolver_ct_hook`'s alter-ego is in fact `X(mksolver_ct_hook)`.

And a quick search for `mksolver_ct_hook` reveals that it's defined in `ct.c` (it's a global), so that file is obviously not being included in the build.

Likewise, `mksolver_hc2hc_hook` is defined in `hc2hc.c`.

Over to you.  There are probably still a few more miles to go, but you should be OK now.

Comment: Thank you for your effort! Both are actually included in the makefile corresponding to the threads library: https://github.com/FFTW/fftw3/blob/master/threads/Makefile.am

Comment: Any idea what's going wrong? Seems like the `if THREADS` clause is not matched. (UPDATE: Noppe, that's not the problem. I've uncommented that if-clause and the problem persists.)

Comment: Not really.  I always build stuff by creating a VS project, from scratch, if that's what it takes.  How many source files are there, roughly?  If it's a manageable number (and, more to the point, not in too many different folders), then that's the approach I'd recommend.  The IDE itself will then help you figure out what's going on (including any weird macro magic - 'Jump to definition').